# Simulate "IOS add to home screen" on desktop google chrome for debug

Tags: ios, google-chrome, debugging, progressive-web-apps

Is there any way to simulate the “IOS add to home screen” function in windows with Google Chrome for debugging ?

I want to debug PWAs (progressive web applications) with a browser like Google Chrome.

For example at this [link](https://www.filimo.com/ios) or [this link](https://m.asanpardakht.net/v2/auth/login) , this two site have a PWA and need to be added to home screen to be shown or debugging.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of so you can do that is if you have a Mac with the XCode iPhone simulator.

Not all PWAs (progressive web applications) are the same, for the second link you can simply use “toggle visibility” option on inspect element sources and use the app, but I doubt you can do that for the first one.